# GetAsync causing timeout issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, async-await

I have below code which causing issue while fetching data

```
 var result = client.GetAsync(requestUri).Result;
```

If I hit `requestUri` from browser then it works fine. but from above code it gives below error.

Error :

> One or more errors occurred.An error occurred while sending the request.The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream.

Stack Trace1 :

> at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
>      at foo(String resultUrl)
>      at dooo(String param, String resultUrl)
>      at foo.<>c__DisplayClass2.<Product>b__0(String x, String y)
>      at foo[T](Func`3 fn)   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>      at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult ar)   at System.Net.TlsStream.EndWrite(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>      at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeadersCallback(IAsyncResult ar)

Stack Trace2

> at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
>      at Foo1(String resultUrl)
>      at Foo2(String param, String resultUrl)
>      at Foo3.<>c__DisplayClass2.<Product>b__0(String x, String y)
>      at Foo4(Func`3 fn)   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>      at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult ar)   at System.Net.TlsStream.EndWrite(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>      at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeadersCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
>         at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.d__0.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
>      at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>      at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
>      at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.d__0.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
>      at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.d__5.MoveNext()

Also i tried awaitable call but no luck. Can we increase request timeout for get  request in this scenario.

Awaitable code I tried

```
var result = await client.GetAsync(requestUri);
                if (!result.IsSuccessStatusCode) throw new Exception(string.Format("Unable to receive data from Uri: {0}", uri.ToString()));

                // write the results
                using (var write = File.Create(filePath))
                using (var read = await result.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
                {
                    read.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                    read.CopyTo(write);
                }
```

Comment: do you have some inner exceptions? there could be more info there

Comment: Don't use `.Result`, either make your call stack async and use `await` or switch from `HttpClient` to `WebClient` and use it's synchronous methods.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain : Yes I tried this also.

Comment: Then show that code rather than using the `.Result` method.

Comment: Instead of using the `quote` feature of stack overflow, put the text of the exception in a code block, it will make it easier to read. Also try using the [copy exception detail to clipboard](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/saraford/2008/08/07/did-you-know-you-can-copy-the-exception-details-with-one-click-from-the-exception-assistant-276/) button and just paste that text in it's entirety in a code block.

Answer (score 0):

If the response is talking long time and you want to increase the timeout just set it on the client: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.timeout(v=vs.118).aspx

Also from looking at the class itself:

```
TimeSpan defaultTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(100.0);
TimeSpan maxTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds((double) int.MaxValue);
TimeSpan infiniteTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(-1.0);
```